# How do I find the source code for Java SE 6 update 10?

Tags: java

At [Java SE Downloads](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp) I may for example download:

- Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) 6 Update 10
- Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 6 Update 10

But I can't find any source code for update 10. If I click [Java SE 6 JDK Source Code](http://download.java.net/jdk6/6u3/promoted/b05/index.html) on the Java SE Downloads page it seems I can only download source for "JDK 6u3 Source". Where can I find the source for update 10? If there isn't any and I use update 10 for development, won't there be serious sync problems if I choose to debug and "step into" the source of a JDK method? (It seems like it should.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java source code for the libs should be included in the JDK installation.

As to the source code for the entire JDK, Sun has indicated that the changes for 6u10 will not make it into an OpenJDK6 release unless the community backports them from the OpenJDK7 releases (ie, Sun isn't doing the work on their own).

Comment: Thanks! I was confused that they offered a separate source download, but only for update 3. It was indeed the libraries I meant, but the whole JVM would of course be interesting to have a look at sometime as well.

Answer (score 1):

My download of JDK 1.6.0_10 has the src.zip already included.

Comment: Thank you. I think it's confusing that they offer a separate source download, but only for update 3.

Comment: As jsight mentioned, this is ONLY the java source. The c source for the jvm and the javac is NOT included in src.zip.